# How To set a Blazor Input Control via Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-binding, blazor, blazor-server-side

I try to set a Blazor InputCheckbox via javascript and expect that the Databinding is executed and the value is written to the Model. But to no avail.
What am I doing wrong?

```
// blazor

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" >
    <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="Model.Checked" class="tripCheckbox" />
</EditForm>


// javascript

const tripCheckBox = container.querySelector('.tripCheckbox');
if (tripCheckBox.checked === false) {
    tripCheckBox.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
    tripCheckBox.checked = true;

} else {
    tripCheckBox.removeAttribute('checked');
    tripCheckBox.checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Because of your comment in user13256346 answer, I don't understand really what is the reason of this. What should call the Javascript function/code: Blazor or some JS logic? Why do you need to go through JS to change the state of the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in changing the value with JS is the Blazor events don't get called.    You have to invoke the DOM events yourself.

Here's a demo page and code, using most of your code:

My JS function loaded in _layout.cshtml.

```js
    <script>
        window.SetMyCheckBox = function()
        {
            const tripCheckBox = document.getElementById('tripCheckbox');
            if (tripCheckBox.checked === false) {
                tripCheckBox.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
                tripCheckBox.checked = true;
                var event = new Event('change');
                tripCheckBox.dispatchEvent(event);
            } else {
                tripCheckBox.removeAttribute('checked');
                tripCheckBox.checked = false;
                var event = new Event('change');
                tripCheckBox.dispatchEvent(event);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And this is a test page:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm Model="@model">
    <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="model.Checked" id="tripCheckbox" />
</EditForm>

<div class="m-2">
    Checked: @model.Checked
</div>

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Clicked"> Change </button>
</div>


@code {
    private Model model = new Model();

    class Model
    {
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
    }

    private async Task Clicked()
    {
      await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("SetMyCheckBox");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to execute your js in some event:

```
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="Model.Checked" class="tripCheckbox" @onclick=OnMyCheckboxClick />
 // Code behind
 [Inject]
 private IJRunTime Js {get; set;}
 private async task OnMyCheckboxClick() { 
   Js.InvokeVoidAsync("YourJSMethod");
 }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I know. I do this, just did not write the whole code but only the necessary one.

Comment: I think that you change the value just in the UI. Try to return value from your js method and assign again to your model, in this case `bind-Value` it will change the value and `statehasChanged ` will be fired.